# How to use train_test_split? Fix error n_samples = 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I'm trying to split the data I am working with into training and testing sets but I get the error that n_samples = 0 when I use the train_test_split function.

Here's my code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(summary, labels, test_size=0.35)
```

summary and labels are lists and after converting them to arrays this is the shape I get:

```
(1248,)
(1248,)
```

They both have 1248 values. Can someone tell me why its not working? Thanks

Error Message:

```
With n_samples=0, test_size=0.35 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, check if this works for you:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

# dummy examples
summary, labels = np.arange(0,1248), np.arange(0,1248)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(summary, labels, test_size=0.35)
```

Test with string list

```
summary, labels = ["hello"]*1248, ["test"]*1248
```

Comment: I added the `np.arrange(0,1248)` part to my code and got this error: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: The summary list contains text as I am trying to train a bag of words model. Hope this info helps.

Comment: @John check the edit, replace those two list with new string lists. It will still work.